# With what API do you perform a read-consistent file operation in OS X, analogous to Windows Volume Shadow Service

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, volume-shadow-service

We're writing a C++/Objective C app, runnable on OSX from versions 10.7 to present (10.11).

Under windows, there is the concept of a shadow file, which allows you read a file as it exists at a certain point in time, without having to worry about other processes writing to that file in the interim.

However, I can't find any documentation or online articles discussing a similar feature in OS X.  I know that OS X will not lock a file when it's being written to, so is it necessary to do something special to make sure I don't pick up a file that is in the middle of being modified?

Or does the Journaled Filesystem make any special handling unnecessary?  I'm concerned that if I have one process that is creating or modifying files (within a single context of, say, an fopen call - obviously I can't be guaranteed of "completeness" if the writing process is opening and closing a file repeatedly during what should be an atomic operation), that a reading process will end up getting a "half-baked" file.

And if JFS does guarantee that readers only see "whole" files, does this extend to Fat32 volumes that may be mounted as external drives?

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- On Unix, once you open a file, if it is *replaced* (as opposed to modified), your file descriptor continues to access the file you opened, not its replacement.
- Many apps will replace rather than modify files, using things like `-[NSData writeToFile:atomically:]` with `YES` for `atomically:`.
- [Cocoa and the other high-level frameworks do, in fact, lock files](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn/tn2037.html) when they write to them, but that locking is advisory not mandatory, so other programs also have to opt in to the advisory locking system to be affected by that.
- The modern approach is [File Coordination](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileCoordinators/FileCoordinators.html). Again, this is a voluntary system that apps have to opt in to.

There is no feature quite like what you described on Windows. If the standard approaches aren't sufficient for your needs, you'll have to build something custom. For example, you could make a copy of the file that you're interested in and, after your copy is complete, compare it to the original to see if it was being modified as you were copying it. If the original has changed, you'll have to start over with a fresh copy operation (or give up). You can use File Coordination to at least minimize the possibility of contention from cooperating programs.